# .bash_login aliases not working

Tags: bash, ubuntu, sh

I am using Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS. I was running a Minecraft server but now it doesn't work anymore. I can still run the server with `sh cds_start.sh` but with the alias cds_start it doesn't do anything. Also when I login it sais that the command is not found. Please help me with this. The sh file is working becuase I can start it manual as showed u above.

Here is the .bash_login

```
alias cds_start='screen -dmSL cds_screen sh /home/jebg/cds_start.sh'
alias cds_console='screen -d -r cds_screen'
```

The location of cds_start.sh is /home/jebg/cds_start.sh
The file:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd "$(dirname "$0")"
cd crafting_dutchman
java -Xmx6G -Xms4G -server -jar spigot.jar nogui
```

Comment: Aliases should be put in `.bashrc`.

Comment: Please avoid using 'he' for shells. It might sound chauvinistic for few. Instead, use 'it'.

Comment: I would just say "odd" rather than chauvinistic. "She" would sound just as odd, since shells aren't living things (or ships).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place it in `.bashrc` instead as non-login interactive shells don't read login start scripts. Also make sure that your `.bash_profile` reads your `.bashrc` so that aliases would be available on login-shells too.

It should have something like this:

```
[[ -f ~/.bashrc ]] && . ~/.bashrc
```

All these details are well-explained in [Bash Startup Files](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html).

#### Updates

Copy your `cds_start.sh` to a backup file like `cds_start.sh.bak` then change its contents to this (not the backup file):

```
#!/bin/bash
exec >/var/tmp/cds_start.log 2>&1
set -x
cd "$(dirname "$0")"
cd crafting_dutchman
java -Xmx6G -Xms4G -server -jar spigot.jar nogui
```

Try to run the command again and show me the output of `/var/tmp/cds_start.log`.

Comment: Okey so the cds_start command still doesn't work but now when i do sh cds_start.sh it sais cds_start.sh 3: cds_start.sh: Syntax error: Bad fd number

Comment: and there is no /var/tmp/cds_start.log file

Comment: What the problem is here is that screen doesn't work with sh looks like

Comment: @BSteurful Please run `dos2unix cds_start.sh` and try again. Also try to use `bash` instead: `bash cds_start.sh`. Besides using `dos2unix` you can also use `sed -i 's|\r||' cds_start.sh`.

Comment: @BSteurful Well I guess you finally got the cause of the error :) However it's unfortunate as it's no longer within my field. You can send a report to the one that distribute the package like your distro team, the game dev, or perhaps minecraft itself.

Comment: Does the server also stop when you run `sh cmd_start.sh`?

Answer (score 0):

Try to put your aliases in .bashrc

Comment: did you log out, log in after adding your aliases ??

Comment: do you have a bash_profile file in your directory? what is its content?